# Flash Programming on Linux

Tags: linux, flash, ide

Does anybody knows good IDE that will allow me to develop flash application on Linux?

Answer (score 4):

You may find some useful suggestions [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425511/what-tools-do-i-need-to-develop-in-actionscript-in-linux).

I use [Flex Builder for Linux](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/) to build applications using [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/). However it can be a bit fiddly to set up currently due to it requiring newer the latest version of the [AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tools/sdk/) (see the [release notes](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/releasenotes.html) on how to upgrade). Also the MXML editor broken with [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) 3.4, so you'll want to stick with 3.3 until they release a patch, or patch 3.4 yourself according to [this](http://www.murf.us/wiki/wiki/Flex34Linux) (untried by me).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Flex Builder, you can use FDT by PowerFlasher, awesome product.

Website:
http://fdt.powerflasher.com

I don't mean to sound a bit mean, but Noldorin's answer is no good at all and misleading, in fact it is fact-less. Flash development restricted to Windows? REALLY?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a command line tool called [LFD](https://github.com/qhwa/lfd) to make it easier to develop flash applications on Linux.

However [LFD](https://github.com/qhwa/lfd) mainly is a util tool based on Flex SDK. You may use your favorite code editor like vim or emacs to edit codes. It's not an IDE.

May it help you!